# Sharepoint calculated column returning #Name?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint calculated column that is as follows:

```
=RIGHT(Hip,LEN(Hip)-INT(FIND("-",Hip)))
```

Basically what this does is return the last digits after the "-" in a string, but for strings that do not contain a "-" it returns #Name? into the column.  Does anyone know of an easy way to change this formula to make it say what I want? Or is it just easier to re-think the formula all together.  Thanks guys.

Comment: What is the column type of 'Hip'? Was that column created with any special characters in the name?

Comment: The column type is just a single line of text, it has numbers and letters, and some have a hyphen, for example: B1155A1-5, and B1155A1 are both examples in the column.

Comment: Did the column name 'Hip' ever have any special characters in it or has it always been 'Hip'?

Comment: Graham, the column is just a text column.  Here is what it contains: Letters, numbers, maybe a hyphen.  That is it.  Nothing strange or weird going on here. Just a simple text column.

Comment: Not the column type, the NAME for the column. Was it ever named something like 'Hip Column', 'Hip!', 'Hip_14_Data'. Errors around #name can be because there are special characters, the column doesn't exist or text that should be treated as a string is treated as a value (122 vs '122'). You can also try [Hip] vs Hip.

Comment: Nope! That is the original name! Here is the issue, sorry I didnt explain it very well - what my calculated column does is go out and search the column "Hip" and finds a hyphen "-" and it returns the value #NAME?, or #VALUE! if the item does not have a hyphen! So my calculated column is working correctly for items that contain a hyphen, but I do not know what to do to handle items that do not have a hyphen!

Comment: Hi Graham, Please help me with a question on list filter on a calculated column - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134641/sharepoint-calculated-column-filter-shows-formula-instead-of-values

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an =IF() statement around this if you're using hyphens that may or may not be there. IF(check for hyphen, hyphen formula, non-hyphen formula), The MSDN information is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx) for the full docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Graham, I appreciate your time.  Your thoughts were definitely helpful!  Here is the final solution -

=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",Shipprod)),RIGHT(Shipprod,LEN(Shipprod)-INT(FIND("-",Shipprod))),"Not OK")